# Getting error in eclipse when pressing f3 after importing Spring Source

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

When pressing F3 or menu Open Declaration in Eclipse Luna I get the following:

Problems opening an editor.
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceType cannot be cast to java.lang.String

I'm using very latest Luna Release 
Version: Luna Release
Build id: 20131003-0825
And I've just followed the Spring Source guide to import all the projects.
Also using the latest JDK 8

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that a Nightly or Integration build of Eclipse 4.4? Neither of which is guaranteed to be stable. 4.4M2 is the latest stable build.

Comment: I have Luna M2 actually...